# How to pass a list of objects as a parameter to a class. Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, object, parameters

How can I pass a list of objecs from main to a class, as parameter?

I need to pass a list of employees to PayrollSystem class as a parameter.

Could someone help, please?

````
    var index = 0
    val employees = mutableListOf(SalaryEmployee(index, "blablabla", 0))
    val x: String = "0"
    while(true) {
        print("Please enter employee name (0 to quit):")
        var input = readLine()!!.toString()
        if (input != x) {
            index++
            print("Please enter salary:")
            var wage = readLine()!!.toInt()
            employees.add(SalaryEmployee(index, input, wage))
        }
        else {
            employees.removeAt(0)
            employees.forEach {
                SalaryEmployee(it.id, it.name, it.monthly_salary).print()
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

class PayrollSystem(list: MutableList<employee>) {

    val temp = list
    fun calculatePayroll(){

    }
}

class SalaryEmployee(id: Int, name: String, val monthly_salary: Int) : Employee(id, name){
    override val id = id
    override val name = name
    fun print() {
        println("Id: $id Name: $name Salary: $monthly_salary")
    }
}

open class Employee(open val id: Int, open val name: String) {

}```
````

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? How to create a list you can pass to the constructor? The exact syntax for calling the constructor with such a list? How to use the list within that class?

Comment: I create a list of objects - "employees" - in main function, using SalaryEmployee class, which inherits "id" & "name" values from Employee class. Then I need to pass that list, as a parameter to PayrollSystem class, which uses calculate_payroll function, that prints each object. I had a problem passing employees list to a PayrollSystem class as a parameter. "class PayrollSystem( <what do I put here to pass the employees list as a parameter>)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are missing `val` keyword in constructor params.

You can make as `var` if you are reassigning the list again.

In kotlin constructor, if you don't define it would be a property of the particular class. So its not possible to access outside constructor.

```
class PayrollSystem(val list: MutableList<Employee>) {

    fun calculatePayroll(){
        //You can access it with list.someThing()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone will face similar task..

````
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var index = 0
    val employees = mutableListOf(SalaryEmployee(index, "blablabla", 0))
    val x: String = "0"
    while(true) {
        print("Please enter employee name (0 to quit):")
        var input = readLine()!!.toString()
        if (input != x) {
            index++
            print("Please enter salary:")
            var wage = readLine()!!.toInt()
            employees.add(SalaryEmployee(index, input, wage))
        }
        else {
            employees.removeAt(0)
            PayrollSystem(employees).calculatePayroll()
            break;
        }
    }
}

class PayrollSystem(val list: MutableList<SalaryEmployee>) {

    val temp = list
    fun calculatePayroll(){
        temp.forEach{
            println("Employee Payroll\n================")
            println("Payroll for: ${it.id} - ${it.name}\n- Check amount: ${it.monthly_salary}\n")
        }
    }
}

class SalaryEmployee(id: Int, name: String, val monthly_salary: Int) : Employee(id, name){

    fun calculateSalary(): Int {
        return monthly_salary
    }
}

open class Employee(open val id: Int, open val name: String) {

}```
````